# How to use global in python

Tags: python, global-variables

```
name = "james"
class Hello:
    global name
    def __init__(self,namek):
        name = namek
        print name
    def sayhi(self):
        print 'Hello my name is', name
a = Hello('john')
a.sayhi()
```

Here why is the global variable name is not changing to john when calling a.sayhi()
where as in the below code value of x is changed to 2

```
x = 50
def func():
    global x
    print('x is', x)
    x = 2
    print('Changed global x to', x)
func()
print('Value of x is', x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the global *in the method*, not in the class scope:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, namek):
        global name
        name = namek
        print name
```

Comment: Martijn's answer is technically correct but using globals to store your state kind of defeats the whole point of using classes...

Comment: Thanks, now I understood concept of global

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should just add this in, since Martijn has pretty much answered your question. To do what you're doing without the `global` keyword, you would do:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, namek):
        self.name = namek
        print self.name
    def sayhi(self):
        print 'Hello my name is', self.name
        return self.name
```

When run:

```
>>> name = "james"
>>> print name
james
>>> a = Hello('john')
john # Because we did print self.name in the __init__()
>>> name = a.sayhi()
Hello my name is john
>>> print name
john
```